# geometry proof - Generalities of Geometry

Tags: geometry

Can you give a hint on how to prove that AB + CD > AF + FC +DE + EB?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: denote the intersection of $AB$ and $CD$ by $X$, and show that $AF + CF < AX + CX$, and $DE + BE < DX + BX$.